# Drawing with glutDisplayFunc (opengl)

Tags: c++, function, opengl, glut

I have a display function, which displays various line segments defined by two points:

```
void display(long total_points, vector<vector<long>> adjmat){
    //stuff here
    glVertex2f(n1,n2);
    glVertex2f(n3,n4);
}
```

and I want to display this segments in a window, and I'm using glut to do it:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //stuff here
    glutDisplayFunc(display(total_points, adjmat));
    glutMainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm getting an error at `glutDisplayFunc()`, `invalid use of void expression`
I need to pass some parameters into `display()` in order to get my desired output.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't pass them as parameters but as globals, it's a shortcoming of glut that way that the functions don't have parameters.

```
long total_points;
vector<vector<long>> adjmat;

void display(){
    //stuff here
    glVertex2f(n1,n2);
    glVertex2f(n3,n4);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //stuff here
    //fill and assign total_points, adjmat
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I see, it's a little bit inconvenient. Can you recommend another library for c++ to create graphics?